# How do I individually mute audio per tab in Chrome or Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

Is there a way (in Chrome/Firefox) to individually mute audio per page/tab? This would be great when listening to music while browsing sites that play audio without asking for user prompt first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since version 42, Firefox has a native icon to show what tabs are playing sounds, and it is possible to click on this icon to mute them:

[image: Firefox 42 sound indicator]

---

On Chrome, type this in the address bar to enable the same feature as Firefox: `chrome://flags/#enable-tab-audio-muting`. After you enable it, you need to restart the browser to make it work.

Comment: I hope someone makes an extension that has mute on by default, and you unmute a tab when you actually want to hear something.

Answer (score 4):

For Chrome: In the address bar, go to `chrome://flags/#enable-tab-audio-muting`, then near the highlighted text on the resulting page, click on 'Enable'. Then, restart Chrome.

> When enabled, the audio indicators in the tab strip double as tab audio mute controls. This also adds commands in the tab context menu for quickly muting multiple selected tabs.

Comment: +1 actually this is better than the accepted answer as it is built in and not 3rd party (no need to download, no risk). It works for both HTML5-based media content AND Flash - I've just tested both. Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll no need to look for the Firefox equivalent to be able to accept this as the answer or otherwise I may consider rewriting the question for just Chrome. I'll come back...

Comment: @therobyouknow See my updated answer: http://superuser.com/a/370557/33758 . Your wish is now a native feature on both browsers.

Comment: +1 on your comment @screener thanks. I had already upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Download Google Chrome MuteTab.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nmkbaaijgpppbokgnhhoakihofedkgcc)

[Download Mozilla Firefox Muter.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/muter/?src=search)

Problem is Google Chrome MuteTab is no way that good as Firefox Muter.

It installs a button which you must click, then there you must start clicking in searching which tab is creating the sound, all this while listening to the loud sound already. MuteTab even sometimes says it there is no sound source (but you can hear it). If it does find it, then you have to click to stop it, after which MuteTab places a cover over that part of the web, with something like ‘object stopped by a MuteTab’.. I uninstalled this extension. It doesn’t protect me from being startled to death by sudden loud noises. And it’s even quicker to find the playing source on the webpage manually and stopping it myself.

Mozilla Firefox Muter however, now that’s something else. It also installs a button, but you only need to click it once. Then it AUTOMATICLY MUTES ALL SOUND. And without making visual changes on the website you are viewing. Even if you (or the website itself) drags the volume slider on youtube video to the right, you won’t hear it, untill you click the button again. It even remembers your last setting after restarting the browser. It’s PERFECT.

Somebody please make addon/extension exactly like this for Chrome, because I’m seriously considering switching to Firefox for this!:)

One more thing: there is also an extension called ’Mute Everything’ available for Chrome.
I have tried, and eventually uninstalled that one, too.
Unlike the great Firefox Muter, it doesn’t concentrate on muting the sound itself, so it can’t be stopped by any script the websites are running, ’Mute Everything’ tries to mute your browser by pausing everything what is currently playing on the website. That will never cover it. There are always new sources developing. It can’t pause/detect websitetalkingheads even now, and who knows what will appear on the web tomorrow. And again, each time you need to click their button FIRST. That is, AFTER you got already startled by yet another very loud sound, right?

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome you can use Volume Master extension to mute (or boost) the volume per tab: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/volume-master/jghecgabfgfdldnmbfkhmffcabddioke